# I have written a C program to convert between decimal, hex and binary

Tags: c, binary, hex, decimal

I cant seem to get hexadecimal portion right, I get the right output but the output keeps going on the screen and never stops until i hit ^z. Havent been able to test the rest of the code yet.
/* This program converts decimal to either binary
* or hexadecimal
*/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*function prints binary of decimal n*/
void binary(unsigned n)
{
/* step 1 recurse dividing by 2*/
if (n > 1)
    bin(n / 2);

/* step 2 print bit*/
printf("%d", n % 2);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char i;
int c;
/*    run till ^d entered
*/
while ((i = scanf("%d", &c)) != EOF) {

    /*        check for argument flag
    */
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-x") == 0)
    {
        /*convert to hexadecimal and print*/
        int decimal = c;
        /*read decimal as flag if ^d is not present in flag*/
        printf("%s", "0x" );
        /*starting 0x formatting for hex*/
        printf("%x", decimal);
        /*new line for next input*/
        printf("\n");


    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0)
    {
        /*            convert to binary and print
        */
        int decimal;
        /*read decimal as flag if ^d is not present in flag*/

        decimal = c;
        binary(decimal);
        /*new line for next input*/
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        /*            prompt help, incorrect flag argument
        */
        printf("%s\n", "Usage: ./convert [-x |-b]");
        break;
    }


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `bin(n / 2)` function?

Comment: You're asking why `while ((i = scanf("%d", &c)) != EOF)` doesn't stop until you press ^z (aka EOF)?

Comment: Your loop `while ((i = scanf("%d", &c)) != EOF) {` should be `while ((i = scanf("%d", &c)) == 1) {` unless you have some devious technique that manages to deal with erroneous input (such as a letter or a punctuation character).  There's no evidence in your code of being devious enough to recover from letters in the input stream.

Comment: sorry bin(n/2) should be binary I though I fixed that!

Comment: `char i;` must be `int`.

Comment: I suspect your binary comes out lsb first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant it to write it like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*function prints binary of decimal n*/
void binary(unsigned n)
{
    /* step 1 recurse dividing by 2*/
    if (n > 1)
        binary(n / 2);

    /* step 2: print bit*/
    printf("%d", n % 2);
}


int main(int argc, char const * argv [])
{
    int num;
    signed char should_run = 1;

    // make sure that an argument was given
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please enter an argument!\n");
        should_run = 0;
    }

    // run until ^d is entered (or an error happened)
    while (scanf("%d", &num) > 0 && should_run) {

        // convert to hex
        if (strcmp(argv [1], "-x") == 0) {
            printf("0x%x\n", num);
        } // convert to binary
        else if (strcmp(argv [1], "-b") == 0) {
            binary(num);
            printf("\n");
        } // print usage
        else {
            printf("%s\n", "Usage: ./convert [-x |-b]");
            should_run = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;(
}
```

## General improvement-tipps

### Check the length of your array before accesing it!

You forgot to check if the user provided one of your arguments (`-x`, `-h`). In general this would lead to "easter eggs" (undefined behaviour ;)) since you assume that `argv` has at least 2 elements in it!

### Improve error handling

Well, my "corrected" code isn't a good example either and I think that this is just in exercise, but it's still good to mention: Take care of the possible errors which can appear. In this case I mean the [scanf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf) function. It would be nice to add some checks to the return value of it.

### Don't split the string to multiple printf statements

You wrote in your code:

```c
 /*read decimal as flag if ^d is not present in flag*/
        printf("%s", "0x" );
        /*starting 0x formatting for hex*/
        printf("%x", decimal);
        /*new line for next input*/
        printf("\n");
```

which could also be changed to a single line: `printf("0x%x\n", decimal)` ;)